# CSS issue with created triangle and background overlap

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index, shapes, css-shapes

I am trying to make a custom element on a wordpress website.  It is one of those downward pointing triangles leading into the next page section, but it also has a number on top of it.

My problem is that the way I have it now, the number becomes hidden behind the background of the section above, and I can't get the number/text to remain ontop, which is exacerbated when seen via mobile. changing the z-index didn't help.

This is the css I am using:

/**to create triangle in middle of page **/

```
div.arrow-down-tan {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 55px solid transparent;
border-right: 55px solid transparent;
border-top: 35px solid #f6f6f6;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -55px;
margin-top: -3%;
padding: 0;
z-index: 2;
```

}

/**to create text ontop of triangle **/

```
div.arrow-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.25%;
    top: -8%;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
```

}

And the html I am using (raw html within a wordpress visual composer page section - which may be part of the problem as well since it is the preceding page section's background which is covering the number):

```
<div class="arrow-down-tan"></div>
<div class="arrow-text">3</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work perfectly in mobile..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/n2w9pv08/

css

```
.d-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 46%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 40px 30px 0px 30px;
    border-color: #CCCCCC transparent transparent transparent;
    /* background-color: red; */
}

.d-arrow-text {
    position: relative; 
    margin: -35px 0px 0px -7px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px; 
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

html

```
<div class="d-arrow">
    <div class="d-arrow-text">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.arrow-down-tan {
position: relative;
margin-left: -55px;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 2;
}
div.arrow-down-tan:after {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 55px solid transparent;
border-right: 55px solid transparent;
border-top: 35px solid red;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -55px;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 2;
  content:"";
}

/**to create text ontop of triangle **/

div.arrow-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 49.5%;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down-tan"><div class="arrow-text">3</div></div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code or else it is nothing but a set of lines of garbled texts. Thanks